# Как сделать форму и обработчик формы в одном файле?

Tags: php, форма

проблема собственно с f5, если нажимаю f5, то пустая форма летит в базу, как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

например если нажата кнопка summit с именем "go"

То обработчик будет начинаться с

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['go'])){
   //заносим в базу
}
```

Comment: Плюс использовать капчу и  как пример и после заноса в базу делать exit(header("Location:/путь"))

Comment: офигеть, гениально и просто) спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sbt'])){
    // fill db
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){location.replace(location.href);}, 3000);
    </script>
    <p>Форма заполнена, вы будете переадресованы через 3 секунды. Если не получилось - жмите <a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">сюда</a>.</p>
    <?php
}
else {
?>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="sbt" />
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```